# Work out percentage count using SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code which tells me which line items are in and out of `SLA`.

How can I turn that into a `%`, so for example when I add them together it will show 98% `SLA` Met.

```
,CASE 
WHEN m.COMPLETED_DT is NULL THEN ''
WHEN m.COMPLETED_DT <= m.SLA_ADJUSTED_DT  THEN 'SLA Met' 
WHEN m.SLA_ADJUSTED_DT IS NULL THEN 'SLA Met' 
ELSE 'SLA Missed' END AS "SLA Desc"
```

If I had the result already, I think it would look something like...

```
SELECT (count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) FROM testtable)) AS YesSLA 
FROM testtable where SLA='Yes';
```

I am not sure how to integrate that with my current statement, I don't believe I can reference the `AS SLA Desc` in a new statement.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show sample data and desired results?

Comment: Looks like your second query as a error, you got `YesSLA` instead of `SLA`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select 100 * avg(case when m.completed_dt <= m.SLA_ADJUSTED_DT or m.SLA_ADJUSTED_DT is null
                      then 1.0 else 0
                 end)
from testtable
where SLA = 'Yes';
```

Comment: the above gives me an error. ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 0):

The code below calculates the % met SLA out of 100 by counting only values that met SLA and then dividing by the total opportunities.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (COMPLETED_DT DATETIME, SLA_ADJUSTED_DT DATETIME)
INSERT @Data VALUES ('5/5/2014', '5/6/2014'), ('5/6/2014', '5/6/2014'), ('5/7/2014', '5/6/2014')

SELECT
    CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM(CASE WHEN COMPLETED_DT <= SLA_ADJUSTED_DT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / COUNT(1) AS [% Met SLA]
FROM @Data
```

**Output**

```
% Met SLA
----------------------
66.6666666666667
```